# How to fill combobox with an Excel-row (string)?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox, userform

I would like to fill a Combobox with a row (CAT, DOG, FISH, ...) in Excel

What I did so far is the following

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Axis As Variant

    Axis = Rows(1)

    ComboBox1.List = Axis

End Sub
```

Compiling works but I can only see the first Value (for example CAT).

And if I try the following code....

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Axis As Variant

    Axis = Columns(1)              '<< Columns instead of Rows

    ComboBox1.List = Axis

End Sub
```

.... the Combobox contains the whole Column.

I tried many things but couldn't find a solution yet.

Therefore I'm asking you guys if anybody could help me please.

Thanks

Comment: `Axis = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"),ActiveSheet.UsedRange).value`

Comment: Thanks for your msg Scott but the Combobox keeps empty if i copy your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a row and want them displayed in a single list you have to transpose

```
ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:C1").Value)
```

You can also do

```
ComboBox1.List = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Fish")
```

To keep a row in a line you have to increase the column count of the combobox.

Comment: thanks SJR but I want to read the first row and fill the combobox with them and don't fill the combobox manually.... if i try your first suggestion, the combobox remains empty :(

Comment: Must be something to do with your set up. Post a screenshot.

Comment: Suggestion referring to first code line: A shorter assignment using the reverse `.Column` property instead of `.List` would be: `ComboBox1.Column = Sheet1.Range("A1:C1").Value` :-)

Comment: @T.M.- very neat. Worth posting as an answer perhaps.

Comment: Hi @T.M. , thanks for your answer. using "ComboBox1.Column = Rows(1).Value" worked very well...

Comment: Fine it *worked*. Try to reduce the items in the Combobox from 16384 columns in row 1 to the actual items count , e.g. via `ComboBox1.Column  = Sheet1.Rows(1).Resize(1,3)` and use fully qualified range references, e.g. using the sheet's CodeName :-) @Ayrix

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is:

```
Dim axis as Variant
Dim lstColumn As Long

'Find last Column
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        lstColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
    End With

'Fill axis with all values from the first row
axis = Application.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lstColumn))

'Write all values of axis in Combobox
ComboBox11.Column = axis
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use following code so that I could easily remove or add the listed item on the reference table.

```
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim refTable As Range

Set wS = Sheet1    
Set refTable = wS.Range("A1" , Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Combobox.List = refTable.Value
```

You could change the refTable range to change "A1" and "A".
Also it could be used for the row to change Rows.Count and xlUp.

Comment: Hi @Andrew7, thanks for your repley... but T.M.'s suggestion above worked very well. I just say "ComboBox1.Column = Row(1).Value" and it works :)